# Raising Concrete Floor then install Vinyl Plank Flooring On Top

Tags: concrete, floor

In order to be level with hall, I need to raise the height of the floor by 1/2"-1" in a room in which I am going to be installing vinyl plank flooring.

Previously the room was carpeted so with the padding it was not as obvious a difference in levels.

The floor is concrete.

What are my options for bringing up the height of the floor ? 
 Can I use foam board, or do I have to use Hardy Backer or DenseShield Or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Need more info here.   Is this a house or apartment, what is the other floor made out of, do you have a layout of the are with openings?   Also do you have a link to the vinyl planks you want to install?

Comment: What does the manufacturer have to say about it?